# SQL database column values choosable depend on values of multiple other columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible to declare a SQL table with the dependancy that one columns values is only valid if it is the value of one of multiple other columns?

Example:

```
Table game {
    id int [pk, incremet]
    player1_id int [ref: < player.id]
    player2_id int [ref: < player.id]
    winner int [???]
}
```

here winner should be as well ref to player.id but only values of eigther player1_id or player2_id (or ..).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `check` constraint:

```
winner int check (winner in (player1_id, player2_id)
```